# is it possible to use input field or text on a image with pysimplegui?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I would like to create an app that have a nice and modern look. I got some experience with pysimplegui but i don't how how to achieve something like this:[example image of what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic6rc.jpg)
I need to create input field on a image and maybe some text on other image. Is this even possible with pysimplegui?
Thanks in advance

Please show some examples of how this can be done

All my tries with this idea failed unfortunately

Comment: yes,  it is possible to do with pysimplegui .

Comment: Maybe you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76144417/11936135

Comment: This kinda works, however could you show me example with the input field?